# Are there number limitations in python?

Tags: python, pi

I have made a Python 3 program to calculate pi for a school project, but it always stops at 16 decimal places. Is there a limit to the length of numbers in python? If so is there a language that I could use that will let me continue?

```
accuracy = int(input("accuracy:  "))

current = 2
opperation = "+"
number = 3
count = 1

for i in range (accuracy):
    if opperation == "-":
        number = number - (4/(current*(current+1)*(current+2)))
        opperation = "+"
    elif opperation == "+":
        number = number + (4/(current*(current+1)*(current+2)))
        opperation = "-"
    current += 2
    print(str(count).zfill(8)) + ":    " + str(number)
    count += 1
```

Comment: Use `decimal` module to avoid length restrictions and, importantly for your case, to avoid floating-point imprecision.

Comment: There's a limit to the precision you can get with a floating point number of a given size. But Python will let you show more digits: `from math import pi; print(format(pi, '.32f'))`.

Comment: If you want to know exactly what the specs are for floats on your system, `import sys; print(sys.float_info)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Note that everything after the initial 16 digits is *wrong*. The extra digits have absolutely nothing to do with π.

Comment: @jmd_dk *"There's a limit to the precision you can get with a floating point number of a given size."* - I literally opened with that!

Comment: Its a computer so its working with binary fractions with a limit of 55 bits of accuracy. When you don't include extra formatting hints, python rounds to the nearest decimal fraction and rounds again to a shorter number so your screen isn't so cluttered. Here's a good read: [15. Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no restriction if you are working with integers and Python 3.x. The precision you get using floating point numbers is however limited. A Python `float` (like `3.14`) is really a C `double`, which have about 16 decimals of precision, as you say.

You can use the `decimal` module to create and work with other floating point numbers with arbitrary precision. Example code:

```
# Normal Python floats
a = 0.000000000000000000001
b = 1 + 2*a
print(b)  # Prints 1.0

# Using Decimal
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100  # Set the precision
a = decimal.Decimal('0.000000000000000000001')
b = 1 + 2*a
print(b)  # Prints 1.000000000000000000002
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for more information on `decimal`.

Comment: Note that using decimal will be slower than the built-in floating-point numbers.

Comment: @Richard Indeed. Though in Python 3.3, the `decimal` module was [sped up](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#new-decimal) by a factor ~100! For newer versions of Python, it should thus not be problematically slow.

Comment: I think is worth notice that in documentation of the decimal module, there is a recipe to calculate pi