# How does python float division work when numerator and denominator are integers and evenly divisible without decimal points?

Tags: python-3.x

I tested these calculations

```
n = 773160767  
n*(n+1)      
n*(n+1)/2
n*(n+1)//2

n*(n+1)/2 % (10**9+7)
n*(n+1)//2 % (10**9+7)
```

Output:

```
597777572401189056
2.9888878620059456e+17
298888786200594528

108373072.0
108373040
```

**Resources I find online all use examples like 3/2 where the result is not a whole number**. I read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html too but it also only describes non-whole numbers but **my example here uses evenly divisible whole numbers so I expect the result should also be a whole number exactly representable** in base2 (298888786200594528) when using float division(/)?

Is there something wrong with the number being too big?
If yes, how big is too big and is there a hardware explanation like below from the link above?
(I can't do experiments lowering n because I don't know if what I'm seeing is what is represented under the hood)

```
almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 
754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision, 
so on input the computer strives to convert 0.1 to the closest fraction
it can of the form J/2**N where J is an integer containing exactly 53 bits
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The examples there (and everywhere else I look) seem to use fractions. I'm trying to understand why my division result which will be a whole number (not 0.xxx or requiring anything behind a decimal point) is not returning the correct whole number as given by //

Comment: floats cannot represent all integers

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thanks! That suggestion led me to a better understanding from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473352/are-there-any-whole-numbers-which-the-double-cannot-represent-within-the-min-max, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553774/are-there-number-limitations-in-python/41553937 explained the difference in limits between python integers and floats.